# Subset of graph with minimum nodes minimum edges pointing out of the subset

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, optimization

Given a Directed Graph $G$ and a node $n$ in that graph I'd like to find a subgraph $S$ of  $G$ with the following conditions:

$n \in S$

$a * $ number of nodes in $S$ + $ b * $ number of edges going from $n_i \in S$ to $n_j \not\in S$ is minimal

Is this a well known problem? Do efficient algorithms for solving it exist? Or maybe approximations? Possibly for the special case of $a = b = 1$?

Background: In software development units of code (e.g. classes) can be considered nodes in a graph with edges being dependencies. If one wants to write tests one has to break all the dependencies, the unit under test depends on. The stated problem is the graph representation of the idea to widen the unit under test in order to break fewer dependencies. The factors $a$ and $b$ represents the perceived cost of adding a class to the unit under test vs. breaking another dependency.

Comment: It's a finite problem (I'm assuming $G$ is a finite graph), so of course there's an algorithm --- just test every possible subgraph.

Comment: Surely you could use linear programming (for some approximation), but I suspect that there might be a way of encoding this into minimum-weight perfect matching.

Comment: Hmm, I looked up linear programming on wikipedia ... the condition doesn't seem to be linear to me since it is based on the non-linear functions 'number of nodes' and 'number of edges'.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited the question to ask for 'efficient' algorithms. I guess I'd even need help making that more precise.

Comment: @JensSchauder You have a variable $x_v$ for every node $v$ and a variable $y_{e}$ for every edge $e$. Then you can do things like $y_{(v,u)} \leq x_v$ or $y_{(v,u)} \leq 1-x_u$ to simulate intersections.

Comment: I don't know if this is of any help, but the case a=0,b=1 is the min-cut problem, which you can solve either by linear programming or with the more 'combinatorial' algorithm (complexity of $n^3$).

Comment: @Antoine doesn't that have the trivial solution of $S = G$? Which wouldn't be of much help for my actual problem.

Comment: @dtldarek Thanx, that is an interesting approach. Definetly gives me a new way to think about the problem.